# How to concatenate line space string in python

Tags: python

I have a python code which is on seperate line and want to get a response with "\n". When I write a code

```
    txt="""a
b
c
d"""
txt = str.join(" ", txt.splitlines())

x = txt.split()

s = ""
for item in x:
    s += item + "\ n"

print(s)
```

it gives me response correctly because i have a space:

```
a\ nb\ nc\ nd\ n
```

But if i take sspace between \ and n I get response back as 
a
b
c
d

I want one blob and should be give me response as a blob of one character.

Comment: To insert a newline, use `\n`. To insert the literal sequence 'backash-n', do `\\n`. You can escape a backslash with another backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Great thank you. I just had to add two // and it worked.

```
txt="""a
b
c
d"""
txt = str.join(" ", txt.splitlines())

x = txt.split()

s = ""
for item in x:
    s += item + "\\n"

print(s)
```